# 644 ではなく 664 パーミッションを利用する特別な理由はあるか

Tags: linux, ubuntu

割としばしば、 ubuntu 系のファイルシステムは 664 パーミッションになっている場合を見かけます。

644 ではなく 664 を利用する特別な理由はありますか？

Comment: 具体的な例（ls -lの結果など）を質問に追記することはできますか？

Answer (score 4):

ユーザープライベートグループという考え方によるものと思われます。

参考URL:

- https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/3683513.html?best_flg=true&isShow=open
- http://web.mit.edu/rhel-doc/4/RH-DOCS/rhel-rg-ja-4/s1-users-groups-private-groups.html